# C# excel Add in

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-2013, excel-addins

I created an excel add in in c# and when I run my code the add in custom buttons come up fine on the excel spreadsheet. But after I publish it and install the add in they dont show up. I am using excel 2013.
I created a group of buttons which should be under home tab

in my custom ribbon tab unde rthe home tab is 'my add in '. but that does not show up when i install the published add in

so i know one thing for sure that my code is fine but there is something messed up with my excel 2013 settings

Comment: could you provide us any code? Also the excel settings under File->options->add-ins->

Comment: Can you please show us some code, and do you get any error messages?